# Computing monodromy groups of curves over function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, etale-cohomology, monodromy

Suppose I consider a hyperelliptic curve given by an equation such as $y^2 = x^{n} + tx + 1$ or some variation on this (where $t$ is a parameter on $\mathbb P^1$ and this curve is really a surface fibered over $\mathbb P^1$).

Some of the fibers will be singular and if we throw away these values of $t$, we get an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb P^1$ with some fundamental group $\pi = \pi_1(U)$. $\pi$ acts on the cohomology group $H^1(X_\eta,\mathbb Z_\ell)$ for $X_\eta$ a smooth fiber and it's image is contained in the symplectic group (that preserves the cup product).

What sort of theorems/techniques/references exist for computing the closure of this image? In particular, are there nice criteria for when it is everything?

I can find a few references (like https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608718 by Chris Hall) for computing the image in $H^1(X_\eta,\mathbb F_\ell)$ but I really do want the entire $\mathbb Z_\ell$ cohomology.

Comment: Picard-Lefschetz theory gives such a result when the family of curves is a Lefschetz pencil of ample divisors on a smooth projective surface.  One modern reference is SGA 7, primarily the second part (I do not have the book with me now . . . ).

Comment: . . .  Of course those results are for the monodromy group acting on the quotient of the cohomology of the geometric generic fiber, $H^1(X_{\overline{\eta}},\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$, by the image of the cohomology of the generic fiber, $H^1(X_{\eta},\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$.  This image is clearly invariant under the action of the monodromy group.

Comment: That's right and Picard-Lefschetz will tell you that there is a set of generators that are transvections (more or less) but my question was really about how to take this information and say something about what the closure looks like. For instance, in the Z/l case, this would be theorem 3.1 in the paper by Chris Hall that I linked.